# Taken to personal collections over your LLC's debt

Tags: contract-law

I have a Florida LLC that I am the sole owner of. I had an agreement with a company to do some work, and they guaranteed me a certain quality level. I assesed the quality when it was done and found that most of it was extremely subpar, and didn't meet the guarantee. I met with them and said this would kill my business, and I couldnt pay for the work unless it was fixed. They decided that fixing it would be too expensive, and just shrugged and walked away. Then at the end of the year they took me to collections. But in my personal name. So now this has been reported to my personal credit report.

Is that legal?

Comment: Did you give them your Tax ID at some point?  My understanding is that for them to have put something on your credit report would have required you disclosing your SSN to the counterparty.  If you signed an agreement under the auspices of an LLC the only tax ID they should have should be the LLC's.  Is that the case?

Comment: Since they're not actually pursuing you in court for money, this is tricky (if that were the case, I'd say get a lawyer). I would contact the credit bureau and dispute it (see https://www.credit.com/credit-repair/dispute-credit-report-error/ for more on that) - I think you should be able to argue they didn't fulfill their side of the contract, so it was void. If they don't remove it, you might be able to get a court involved, but you'd need to consult a lawyer as to how that's litigated.

Comment: @childofsoong someone failing to fulfil a contract doesn't make it void - it creates a breach of the contract. A void contract is one that doesn't exist.

Comment: @DaleM well that's why I'm not a lawyer!  Thanks for the correction!

Comment: We had a verbal agreement as to the quality guarantee and rates. And a non-disclosure agreement in writing. I didn't give them my EIN or tax id so far as I can remember. The NDA was with the LLC, and I signed it as president.

Comment: @childofsoong they should probably call the credit bureau and explain that they don't owe the money; the LLC does.